# django 3 - how to set Article model foreign key as logged in user id?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

am a new learner of django 3. trying to build a blog app where user can create article & article author foreign key will be logged in user id. To do it my model.py is

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  bio = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Category(models.Model):
  category = models.CharField( max_length=50)       
  description = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.category

class Article(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
  content = models.TextField()
  category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

according to model I made a form by forms.py

```
 from django import forms
 from django.forms import ModelForm

 from .models import *


class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Article
    fields = '__all__'
```

To present this form my views function is...

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
  articles = Article.objects.all()
  form = ArticleForm()

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    return redirect('bloglist')

context = {'articles':articles, 'form': form}
return render(request, 'bloglist.html', context)
```

and template code is...

```
 <form method="POST" action="" class="form-inline">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{form }}
     <input class="btn btn-primary mb-2" type="submit" name="Submit">
 </form>
```

In this way normally I store data into database, but this way author field need to set manually, but I want to know how to set this author field as logged in user id? I've searches many website from google & youtube but not found my answer. someone please help me to solve the prob? how to set author field as logged in user id?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you must set a relationship between Author and User.You can do this with adding this to your Author model

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='author')
    #your other fields
```

You can access your logged user with request.user . For assign author to your article:

```
if form.is_valid():
    article = form.save(commit=False) 
    article.author = request.user.author # you can check here whether user is related any author
    article.save()
```

Comment: user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='author') if add this line pycharm show error user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='author')
NameError: name 'User' is not defined

Comment: Have you any user model?

Comment: user = models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='author') is this line will be include in Author model or Article model?

Comment: I've created superuser, so may be I've user model from super user

Comment: If you are using Django's default user model, you must add this from django.contrib.auth.models import User to your imports

Comment: To create blog article I don't use default user model. I've created 3 model for post article, which is Author, Category & Article

Comment: How do you use login system? You need a user model